# Introducing Stack Exchange Research Support and Fellowship Program

Tags: discussion

The mission of Stack Exchange is to make the internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions. The Stack Exchange Fellowship Program aims to support students conducting research in subjects related to our academic Q&A sites in order to (a) increase the quality of information in a particular subject and (b) facilitate the exchange of information between experts in the field. Individual awards range from 250 to 1000 dollars (USD).

Applicants should be advanced undergraduate, graduate students or professionals pursuing research related to one the following Stack Exchange sites:

- English
- Linguistics
- Physics
- Statistics
- Theoretical Physics
- Theoretical Computer Science

Applications will be accepted on a rolling basis starting immediately. For more details and to apply, check out the [application](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37818223/SE%20Fellowship%20Application.docx)!

We are also accepting volunteers from the community to help review applications. Volunteers should have some level of expertise in the subject area (professors and those who have or are pursuing advanced degrees are ideal candidates). Following the first wave of submissions, those selected to be Stack Exchange Fellows will be asked to review 3 to 4 new applications. To facilitate the review process, reviewers will rate applications on several scales instead of making judgments on funding. You can find the Reviewer Form [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37818223/Reviewer%20Sheet.docx).

Reviewers and successful candidates are encouraged to customize the "about me" section of the user profile by including information on:

1. Area of expertise and current occupation
2. Key academic goals/milestones
3. Role in the Fellowship program (applicant, reviewer, fellow, both)
4. SE grant project, if applicable

If you have any questions regarding the Fellowship Program, or would like more information about applying or becoming a reviewer, please email *academics@stackexchange.com*.

Edited: Applications accepted on a rolling basis until December 31, 2011.

Comment: Are reviews blinded?  I have been informing some colleagues of this opportunity, and therefore would potentially have a conflict of interest if I were asked to review applications by their students.

Comment: @whuber Yes, great question- thanks for bringing up. Reviews will be blinded.

Comment: in my opinion, it's a bit unclear how the funding should be used. Hardware needed for the project ? Subsistence of the fellow for the duration of the project ? In the latter case, the estimated time needed to complete the project (e.g. as estimated by the reviewer) combined with the cost of living where the project proposer lives would determine the proposed amount of funding.

Comment: @AndreHolzner Did you read the application? Prototypical uses of funds are listed in there. Also, the time frame needed for the project is up to the applicant, not the reviewer.

Comment: @SethRogers ok, I see, the eligible expenses are listed on three.

Comment: How are the funds distributed? Direct to the applicant, reimbursed from StackExchange, or through the department? It helps determine the Effort:Reward ratio for dealing with departmental red tape.

Comment: @EpiGrad Once the proposal is approved, SE will send the awarded funds directly to the applicant.

Comment: 1) are applications still being accepted? I just noticed the banner ad on stats.SE. If the deadline has past, please consider removing the banner ad. 2) Does my work _really_ have to fall into one of those fields? I work in neuroscience and human-computer interaction, and my work requires lots of statistical knowledge-- but it doesn't fall into any of the categories listed. Can I still apply?

Comment: @Jeff Thank you for your questions! Applications are currently not being accepted as the deadline for this round was on Dec. 31. The banner ads should not have been running- that is now corrected. Thanks again Jeff.